# Trigger to insert new quote number in this format

Tags: database-trigger

I am very new at triggers - actually this will be my first one.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

When I create a new Sales Opportunity, the Quote no field needs to spit out a number starting from this Q1500/09/2017 so Q is the prefix, 1500 is the first quote number, 09 the month and 2017 the year.

Can someone assist me in getting this right - do i need a SP and a table in order for my trigger to work correctly?

`Quote_No` is a table field so I'm guessing it should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quote_Pref_No](
    [Yr] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Mth] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [Quote_Pref] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Quote_No] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then the SP:

```
Create Proc [dbo].[New_Quote_Num] @ClientID varchar(24),@ContactNum int, @Year varchar(4), @mth varchar(2)

As

Begin

    Declare @Pref varchar(5),
        @Num int,
        @QuoteNo varchar(255)       

        Select @QuoteNo = B.Description
        From dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl A inner join dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl B
             on A.Type_Id = B.Type_Id and A.Code_Id = B.Code_Id and A.Type_Id = 117
        Where A.Client_Id = @ClientId and A.Contact_Number = @ContactNum

        Select @Pref = Quote_Pref, @Num = Quote_No + 1
        From dbo.Quote_Pref_No
        Where Yr = @Year and Mth = @Mth


        Set @QuoteNum = 'Q/'+Right(@Year,2)+'/'+Right(@mth,2)+'/'+@Pref+case when Len(@Num) <= 3 then Right('000000'+Convert(Varchar(55),@Num),3) else CONVERT(Varchar(55),@Num) end

        Insert into dbo.O_QuoteNo(Client_Id,Contact_Number,Type_Id,Code_Id,O_QuoteNo)
        Values(@ClientId,@ContactNum,13,0,@QuoteNum)

        Update dbo.Quote_Pref_No
        Set Quote_No = @Num
        Where Yr = @Year and mth = @mth

End

Grant execute on dbo.New_Quote_Num to CRMGroup

GO
```

I just dont know how to generate the month and year together.

Trigger code:

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[QuoteNew]
on [dbo].[AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl] after insert
As

Declare @ClientId varchar(24),
    @ContactNum int,
    @TypeId int,
    @Year varchar(4),
    @quoteYear varchar(4),
    @mth varchar(2)


Select @ClientId = Client_Id,
    @ContactNum = Contact_Number,
     @TypeId = TYPE_ID,
     @Year = CONVERT(varchar(4),Datepart(yyyy,DateCol)) from inserted
    @mth = convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm,Datecol)) from inserted
Select @quoteYear = Yr from dbo.quote_Pref_No where Yr = @Year
select @mth = mth from dbo.quote_Pref_No where mth = @mth

If @TypeID = 117 and @QuoteYear is null or @quoteYear = ''

    Begin

        Execute dbo.New_Year_Certs @Year

        Execute dbo.New_quote_Num @ClientId,@ContactNum,@Year

    End

If @TypeID = 117 and @quoteYear = @Year

    Begin

        Execute dbo.New_Cert_Num @ClientId,@ContactNum,@Year

    End







GO
```

Do I need to create a separate SP for month or can I do both month and year in one SP?